# Making a Toast message from a separate Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, toast

I try to send a Toast Message from a Thread to the UIThread when clicking a button.
However, every time I click the button the Toast does not appear.
I am using a Handler to do this.

This is the full code, in case I made a major mistake somewhere:

```
package google.map.activity;

//imports

public class GoogleMapActivity extends MapActivity {

int lat = 0;
int lng = 0;
Location location;

MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;
private MapController mapController;
private MapView mapView;
private LocationManager locationManager;

// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.googlemapactivity);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    mapView.setSatellite(false);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(19);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5,
            0, new GeoUpdateHandler());

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 5, 0, new GeoUpdateHandler());

    // //////---Switch to
    // Start/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Button switchToMain = (Button) findViewById(R.id.switchtomain);
    switchToMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    // ////--Call a
    // Cab/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    Button getCab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GetCab); // create the Button

    final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

    getCab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                true);

        Location locationTest = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider); // get

        // last
        // known

        // location fix from
        // locationManager

        public void getAddress() {

            String msg = null;

            Looper.prepare();

            if (locationTest == null) {

                bestProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

            }

            Location location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale
                    .getDefault());// create
            // new
            // GeoCoder

            String result = null; // initialize result

            try { // try to get Address list from location of bestProvider
                List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                        location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                    Address address = list.get(0);
                    // sending back first address line and locality
                    result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", "
                            + address.getLocality();// set result
                    // to
                    // Streetname+Nr.
                    // and City
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                msg = String.format("IOException!!");

            } finally {

                if (result != null) {

                    msg = String.format(result);

                    // Looper.loop();

                } else
                    msg = String.format("Keine Position");
            }
            Message myMessage = new Message();
            Bundle resBundle = new Bundle();
            resBundle.putString("status", msg);
            myMessage.obj = resBundle;
            handler.sendMessage(myMessage);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    // Looper.myLooper();
                    // Looper.prepare();

                    getAddress(); // get the Address

                    Location locationTest = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

                    if (locationTest == null) {
                        bestProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
                    }

                    Location location2 = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

                    int lat = (int) (location2.getLatitude() * 1E6); // get
                    // position
                    // for GeoPoint
                    int lng = (int) (location2.getLongitude() * 1E6);

                    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng); // create
                    // GeoPoint
                    // for
                    // mapController
                    mapController.animateTo(point);

                }

            }).start();

            // toast.show();

        }
    });

}

public Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
};

public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
        mapController.animateTo(point); // mapController.setCenter(point);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Edit: Solved it by using this:

```
Handler toastHandler = new Handler();
Runnable toastRunnable = new Runnable() {public void run() {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}};
```

In the UIThread and this:

```
toastHandler.post(toastRunnable);
```

in the background thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        // Here you can make a Toast
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your toast needs to be done in the UI thread. Here's how to do that:

Note: `ClassName.this` is needed because `this` by itself will refer to your anonymous `Runnable` class.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    Toast.makeText(ClassName.this, R.string.something, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: I want just wanted to add *why* this is needed: You cannot access the GUI from another thread unless it is the "main" thread (often referred to as the GUI thread). This method pushes the toast message method onto the GUI thread and thus it can be displayed.